# Mongoose avoid duplicate entities

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I try to write a programm that insert countries into mongoose database. All countries is saved in a xml file and is utf-8 encoded.

First of all, i read all countries from xml file and keep it in an array. The countries array looks like this

```
[ { language: 'en', iso: 'WF', name: 'Wallis and Futuna' },
{ language: 'en', iso: 'EH', name: 'Western Sahara' },
{ language: 'en', iso: 'YE', name: 'Yemen' },
{ language: 'en', iso: 'ZM', name: 'Zambia' },
{ language: 'en', iso: 'ZW', name: 'Zimbabwe' },
{ language: 'en', iso: 'AX', name: 'Åland Islands' } ]
```

And then i create country schema in mongoose, looks like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true } };
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Database connect
var uristring =
    process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost/townspeech';

mongoose.connect(uristring, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        //console.log('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
    } else {
       //console.log('Successfully connected to: ' + uristring);
    }
});

// Country schema   
var CountrySchema = new Schema({
    language: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
    iso: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
}, { autoIndex: false });


module.exports = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
```

After then, insert all countries into database, that i had kept in the array.

My question is now, when i execute my program many times, will i find duplicate entities in database or not? I will avoid duplications from name and iso.

Look at schema definition, i define fields iso and name as unique:true, it will be work?

Comment: Well...have you tried?

Comment: yes, but i can not recognize, because a lot of data.

Comment: Well, just execute your program a second time and perform a query to see if you get duplicates. It's really not that hard.

Comment: first of all, it is the schema definition correct?